# Question about modulus of large numbers in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, number-theory

I used Fermat's Little Theorem and found that 40^65 % 7 = 3. But when I use the following code in Python the answer it prints is 2.0:

```
print((math.pow(40,65) % 7))
```

Why does Python give the result incorrectly as 2.0?

Thank you

Comment: `math.pow(40,65)` returns a float, which is an approximation. Try `(40**65)%7` instead.

Comment: Thanks khelwood! I didn't know that it was simply an approximation. (40**65)%7 really helped me too. How can i give you "points" and close this question?

Comment: I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`math.pow(40,65)` returns a float, which is an approximation.

Try `(40**65) % 7` instead.

Once you're happy that the maths works, you can use the built-in function [`pow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) to calculate powers and mods in combination:

```
pow(40, 65, 7)
```

Comment: Except that you really should be doing `pow(40, 65, 7)`, which does modular exponentiation, and scales a lot better than computing the whole exponential and then taking the modulus at the end. (That `pow` is the builtin `pow`, not `math.pow`.)

Comment: @user2357112 I'm not sure that would serve the OP's purpose in this question, but it is definitely helpful to know about.